# Media query does not change banner image's display property for mobile view

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, media-queries

So on my mobile view, I want the banner to show my mobile image and I was alternating the display properties in the media query. This is my first question on Stack, sorry if I omitted something.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-container">

    <img class="desktopimage" src="../resources/images/indeximage.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="mobileimage" src="../resources/images/mobileindeximage.jpg" alt="">

  </div>



  <div class="intro-container">
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Work hard today, Be Lean tomorrow.</h2>

      <h4></h4>

      <p></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then here I have the scss for it, the DevTools in the browser crosses off the **display:block** property in the media query.

```css
        .banner {
          display: flex;
          width: 100%;
          flex-direction: column;
          position: relative;

          .row {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;

            .image-container {
              min-width: 100%;

              .desktopimage {
                width: 100%;
                height: 95vh;
              }

              .mobileimage {
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
              }
            }

            .intro-container {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
              position: absolute;
              border-radius: 20px;
              opacity: 0.9;
              right: 1rem;

              .intro {
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.9;
                padding: 1em;
                color: rgb(7, 6, 6);

                h2 {
                  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
                  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        @media (max-width: 900px) {
          .desktopimage {
            display: none;
          }

          .mobileimage {
            display: block;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.banner .row .image-container` in the selector (i.e. the elements into which your two classes are nested in your sass code) to achieve at least the same level of **CSS specifity** as for the default styles:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
 .banner .row .image-container {
      .desktopimage {
        display: none;
      }

      .mobileimage {
        display: block;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so silly of me. I thought on media queries, the query would target straight the element which I want, without specificity.